# How question per day is calculated on area 51?

Tags: support

Currently, we have 432 questions and it has been 32 days in beta,  `432/32 = 13.5`, but area 51 says question per day is 6.7 . So I guess it doesn't use whole history of site. So where does that number come from? Last day, last week, or what?

Comment: Though not off-topic here, this question could have better credibility at [discuss.area51.stackexchange.com](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As answered by a [StackExchange employee](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146719/david-fullerton) [**here**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73217/bug-in-area-51s-questions-per-day), it is the **average number of questions per day over the last two weeks.**

If you observe, just hovering over the box that shows Questions per day would give you this fact.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, our.questions per day is reduced considarably in last two weeks

Comment: This tends to be normal, @tachyons.